# Defining classes or IDs on every page or single document?

Tags: class, magento

I'm new to magento and programming

Do I have to define my classes on every block `and/or` page on magento?

For example, I want to use `text-center` on multiple pages, do I define what `text-center` is in `<head>`

if not can you tell me what document I need to create?

Answer (score 0):

Every page has class `page` which is defined in layout. You can find layout file in `app\design\frontend\{yourTheme}\default\template\page` folder with name `1column`, `31column` ...etc. Layout is defined according to the page.

You can add new class to layout file for all the pages of same layout.